# Convert a DateTime Zone to Other DateTime Zone

Tags: android, flutter, dart, datetime, dart-pub

I am getting a datetime in utc and want to convert it to different timezones.

String utcTime is what I am getting from API. timeZone is what I want my converted time to be.
I am using timezone package from pub.dev
Return statement is not working and I am getting same value I am giving in input.
eg. I am giving 2023-03-30 13:51:11.130391 and getting the out same: 2023-03-30 13:51:11.130391.

Please help, and let me know if there is any other way that I can approach.

```
String formatdatetime(String utcTime,String timeZone) {
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  final DateTime now = DateTime.parse(utcTime);
  print(now);
  final Location pacificTimeZone = tz.getLocation("Asia/Kolkata");
  print(tz.TZDateTime.from(now, pacificTimeZone));
  return DateFormat('dd/MM/yy hh:mm aa').format(tz.TZDateTime.from(now, pacificTimeZone));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following modification to your example works for me:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:timezone/standalone.dart' as tz;

void main(List<String> args) async {
  await tz.initializeTimeZone();
  const time = '2023-03-30 13:51:11.130391';
  final result = formatdatetime(time, 'Asia/Kolkata');
}

String formatdatetime(String utcTime, String timeZone) {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.parse(utcTime);
  print('UTC:      $now');
  final tz.Location toZone = tz.getLocation(timeZone);
  final adjusted = tz.TZDateTime.from(now, toZone);
  print('Adjusted: $adjusted');
  return DateFormat('dd/MM/yy hh:mm aa').format(adjusted);
}
```

Some additional advice: don't convert directly from a UTC ISO-8601 string to a local time string. Parse the string into a DateTime object, ensure it's in UTC, then leave it that way in memory and in storage if you're saving it somewhere. Only convert it to local time when it becomes necessary, such as when it's displayed in the UI. Having the time in a strongly typed and consistent format will save a lot of headaches in the future.